# connecting social like plugin and my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

This is my first thread so be easy on me :) . For all problems i had i found a solution here at stackoverflow, but this one i can' figure out.

So, I wanted to make like button at my website (not facebook page, but actual website) , so when an user likes some URL, it appears in his timeline (website is with articles, so every article has its URL) . Mosh important, i wanted that the like would be in form " 'someone' liked 'something' ON 'SOME_PAGE'" . This "on some page" is the wanted part actually. After some research i found out that i need open graph protocol and facebook app to make that happen. So i followed this tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ .

Right now, when i like something on my webiste, it appears in my timeline like it should, in form :" name surname liked "something" on "some_facebook_app/webpage" , so its all ok if I make the like, but when someone else likes if (person that is not admin for this app) , it appears as regular link, actually it gets rendered with open graph protocol as in , it shows title, description and picture, but it doesnt connect to my facebook app, there is no "on facebookapp" part. Also, when i come from my friends facebook account to my timeline, likes i made on this particular website are not visible. I dont know is that the problem because i cant find anywhere anything about this (i subscribed app details, i dont know if that is the problem...) . Also, only my face show up in likes, even when i know for sure that my friends liked that particular link too, but I assume that this is problem that is associated with the previous one (because like is not "connected" to facebook app) .

I'm new in this facebook developer stuff, and this facebook app is a big black hole for me...

Comment: To make myself clearer, [here](http://pokit.org/get/?af752e9633106e37e0c30f7c070c4204.jpg) is what I get when I, admin of specific facebook application, like the page on website, and [here](http://pokit.org/get/?5506065de2345219e7b2fc3842b92142.jpg) is what happens when i like that same link with random facebook person that is not admin on that facebook application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was. I didnt know what sandbox mode meant, so after disabling it, app is now visible to everyone. Nobody actually helped me here, but thanks anyway :) .